# C++ Inheritance, calling a derived function from the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, function, class

How can I call a derived function from a base class? I mean, being able to replace one function from the base to the derived class.

Ex.

```
class a
{
public:
   void f1();
   void f2();
};

void a::f1()
{
   this->f2();
}

/* here goes the a::f2() definition, etc */

class b : public a
{
public:
   void f2();
};

/* here goes the b::f2() definition, etc */    

void lala(int s)
{
  a *o; // I want this to be class 'a' in this specific example
  switch(s)
  {
   case 0: // type b
     o = new b();
   break;
   case 1: // type c
     o = new c(); // y'a know, ...
   break;
  }

  o->f1(); // I want this f1 to call f2 on the derived class
}
```

Maybe I'm taking a wrong approach. Any comment about different designs around would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Declare f2() virtual in the base class.

```
class a
{
public:
       void f1();
       virtual void f2();
};
```

Then whenever a derived class overrides `f2()` the version from the most derived class will be called depending on the type of the actual object the pointer points to, not the type of the pointer.

Comment: Thx, now I know what the 'virtual' thing was... :D

Comment: Actually, virtual is THE feature that makes real OOP possible in C++.

Comment: Yeah, well... at least the inheritance part of it... imio (in my ignorant opinion), OOP would still be practical just using compositions...

Comment: @huff: True.  `virtual` isn't exactly the enabling idiom as far as OOP goes, precisely.  `virtual` makes polymorphism possible, which is one part of OOP.

Answer (score 5):

Declare f2() as [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).