# Base class function not overriding superclass function when called from a pointer of the superclass

Tags: c++, function, pointers, inheritance

I have a class `sub` which inherits from a class `super`. They both define a function `void function()` (so the function in `sub` overrides that in `super`). I create a `super` pointer and assign it a new instance of `sub`. I then call `function()` on the instance of `sub` through the  `super` pointer. However, the function in `super` is called, not that in `sub`. I want it to call the function in `sub`, not that in `super`. How should I do this?

```
#include <cstdio>  

class super {  
    public:
    void function() {  
        printf("Super\n");  
    }  
};  

class sub: public super {  
    public:  
    void function() {  
        printf("Sub\n");  
    }  
};  

int main() {  
    super *p;  
    p = new sub;  
    p->function();  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Functions aren't virtual by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Inheritance, calling a derived function from the base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116782/c-inheritance-calling-a-derived-function-from-the-base-class)

Comment: You can cast the pointer to your subclass before calling the function. `((sub *)p)->function();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration should be:

```
virtual void function()
```

I'm rusty on C++, but basically if the function isn't virtual, the compiler will take you on your word that if the pointer is to a super, the function() call goes to super::function().  Virtual tells it that you want it to figure out the right one instead.  In practice, this means it'll create a vtable instead, and do an indirect lookup.  Then it doesn't matter whether it's a super* or sub*, because they will both have a vtable, and the vtable will point to the right version of function() for the actual type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
class super {  
    public:
    virtual void function() {  
        printf("Super\n");  
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

- To call a derived class function using a base class pointer, you need to implement the concept called function overriding.
- But in your case, you implemented function hiding, not function overriding.
- To override a function, both derived class and base class should have the same function signature and base class function declaration must be declared with the **`virtual`** keyword.
- If you use the **`virtual`** keyword in base class declaration, then a virtual table in the memory and it take care of calls to most derived function of the class chain.

For more understanding, read the following:

- [Function Hiding](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/116-adding-changing-and-hiding-members-in-a-derived-class/)
- [Function Overriding](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/)
- [Virtual Table](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/)